# Filtering MySQL output without referencing alias but where SUM(CASE) is used

Tags: mysql

With a view to remediating missing userIDs in our database, I'm trying to look at instances where - within the same table, the same user is found with and without IDs. So far, I have a rough result using the following:

```
SELECT users,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UserID = ""  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithoutIDs,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UserID <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithIDs,
    COUNT(*) as TOTAL
    FROM table.users
GROUP BY name;
```

I would now like a `where InstancesWithIDs > 0` filter applied to the table. But as I keep reading, I can't reference an alias in the filter. From googling around, *I think* the best I've gotten is:

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT users,
            SUM(CASE WHEN UserID = ""  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithoutIDs,
            SUM(CASE WHEN UserID <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithIDs,
        COUNT(*) as TOTAL
        FROM table.users) A
where InstancesWithIDs > 0;
```

But this then displays all results as a single record.

```
users    ||   InstancesWithoutIDs   || InstancesWithIDs 
A. Fisher            62588                  947711
```

How can I get the full table displayed, as I did with the top query?

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Having (only when you use GROUP BY) like this:

```
SELECT users,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UserID = ""  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithoutIDs,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UserID <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InstancesWithIDs,
    COUNT(*) as TOTAL
    FROM table.users
GROUP BY name
HAVING InstancesWithIDs > 0;
```

HAVING would be the equivalent to WHERE but for aggregated functions

Comment: That's great! works perfectly, thank you!